# How to connect to firebase server using php via xmpp protocol

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting hard tome to send xmpp request to firebase server using php, I have tried following code, but  not getting how to proceed further

```
set_time_limit(0);  // some time connection take while  
include_once 'JAXL-3.0.0/jaxl.php';
$client = new JAXL(array(
'jid' => 'xxxxxxxxx@gcm.googleapis.com',
'pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',//api key
'host' => 'gcm.googleapis.com',
'port' => 5235,
'force_tls' => true,
'strict' => FALSE,
'ssl' => TRUE,
'auth_type'=> 'PLAIN',
'log_level' => JAXL_DEBUG,
'protocol' => 'tls'
));
//add a callback for authorisation success
    $client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() { 
        echo "authenticated";
    });

     $client->add_cb('on_auth_failure', function() { 
        echo "authentication failed";
    });

    $client->add_cb('on_connect', function() { 
        echo "connected";
    });

    $client->add_cb('on_stream_start', function() { 
        echo "Stream started";
    });
//start the client
$client->start();
```

In callback method I am getting response as connected, Please help me to complete this code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you first check the full documentation on [Implementing the XMPP connection server protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) wherein the important details which you need to know are being discussed such as the following:

- Establishing a connection
- Authentication (with snippets that illustrate how to perform authentication in CCS)
- Downstream messages

And, you may want to check these references for more information and to help you with the implementation:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging XMPP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref) documentation
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging XMPP protocol app server written in pure PHP](https://github.com/sourc7/FCMStream)
- [Android Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidlearning.in/android-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-php-mysql/)
- [XMPPHP](https://github.com/Drarok/xmpphp)

Hope that helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have already gone through it. My problem is that I am not getting hoe to implement it using JAXL in my app server, beacause I am not that good at PHP. so please help me in this if possible. I have also tried XMPPHP but didn't get success.